# Probleme cloning row in jQuery

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a problem cloning a row in jQuery.

## My JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addLine').click(function() {
      $('.data-line').last().clone({
      withDataAndEvents: false
    }).insertBefore('.data-line')();
    });                 
  });
</script>
```

## My HTML:

```
<div class="form-group data-line"></div>
<a href="#" id="addLine"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>
```

## My problem:

Each time i click on my link (#addLine), it clone the my row.
But On second click, it will copie the two rows.

How to allow to copy only one row ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `insertBefore` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addLine').click(function() {
    $('.data-line').last().clone({
      withDataAndEvents: false
    }).insertBefore('.data-line:nth-child(1)');
  });                 
});
```

In your code you insert your cloned node before each element with class name `.data-line`.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/hukiqaqi/1/edit)**

Comment: How to remove it after?

Answer (score 0):

`.insertBefore('.data-line')` inserts the cloned element before every existing `.data-line` element. So it doesn't clone the two rows, it creates two clones of the last row and inserts each of them before every existing `.data-line`.

You can use `.insertBefore('.data-line:first')` instead instead, to only insert the clone before the first `.data-line` element.